# Creating a list that gives a specific value at even indexes and another value at odd indexes

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want to create a list say chelsea_fc that will populate the value "EPL Champions" in even indexes and "Manager Sacked" at odd indexes till a given range. (dont want to hard code the range)

I am getting confused as how to do it. Please help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, your existing code will help us respond appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally write it as you would say it!

```
>>> ['a' if i % 2 else 'b' for i in range(10)]
['b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: 0 is an even number, why does the list give me b at index 0?

Comment: @ArkaBose because `0 % 2` is `0` (so even) but `0` evaluates to `False` so the `else` option is used. You could do `if i % 2 == 0` and then the output would be as you want. Or you could do `if not i % 2` which would just flip them around. Or you could just say `'b' if i % 2 else 'a'`. It's up to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (or any other list that repeat itself) like this:

```
 chelsea_fc = ['Manager Sacked', 'EPL Champions']*(range_of_choice/2)
 print(chelsea_fc)
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan for the alternative